# Using CollectionViewSource in App.xaml

Tags: c#, wpf

I m trying to use CollectionViewSource in App.xaml to share the same collection in 2 different controls.

If I place the code in the UserControl.Resources i works Ok

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="AppsCollectionViewSource" Source="{Binding UsersList}"/>
```

But if I move it to the **App.xaml** Inside the **Application.Resources/ResourceDictionary** the controls can still resolve the "AppsCollectionViewSource" key but after I start the application the lists are not populated with the data.

I m also seeing the error

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=UsersList; DataItem=null; target element is 'CollectionViewSource' (HashCode=57005908); target property is 'Source' (type 'Object')
```

So Appears that it cannot resolve the property name UsersList when the **CollectionViewSource is in App.xaml** (inside the user control works ok).

The DataContext is being passed to the MainWindow.cs like

```
DataContext = new UsersViewModel();
```

Any Ideas how to do this?

Comment: In my opinion, you a going to do something wrong. If you want to reuse same collection with 2 controls, you have to bind this collection twice for each control, but dont make it accessable from app resources.